# Hibernate cache by other column than id

Tags: hibernate, hazelcast

I am trying to properly set the caching mechanism for Hibernate + Hazelcast (in Spring 4) and I am facing some problems when the select is done by a different column than the ID. Below is a simplified version of my model:

```
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE,
        region = HibernateCacheConstants.LISTENER_REGION_NAME)
@Entity
@Table(name = "books")
public class Book {
    @Id
    @Column
    UUID id;

    @Column
    String name;

    @Column
    UUID authorId;
}
```

Now, I have the following configuration for Hibernate:

```
properties.setProperty("hibernate.show_sql", "true"); // temporary activated to see exactly the DB hits
properties.setProperty("hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache", "true");
properties.setProperty("hibernate.cache.region.factory_class",
                "com.hazelcast.hibernate.HazelcastLocalCacheRegionFactory");
```

Now, some tests:
When retrieving by ID

```
booksDao.get(bookId); // hits the database. Looged:
// Hibernate: select this_.id as id1_0_0_, this_.name as name2_0_0_, this_.author_id as authorId_se3_0_0_ from LIBRARY.books this_ where this_.id in (?)
booksDao.get(bookId); // retrieved from cache, as intended
booksDao.get(bookId); // retrieved from cache, as intended
```

```
booksDao.getByAuthorId(authorIdId); // hits the database. Looged:
// Hibernate: select this_.id as id1_0_0_, this_.name as name2_0_0_, this_.author_id as author_se3_0_0_ from LIBRARY.books this_ where this_.author_id in (?)
booksDao.getByAuthorId(bookId); // hits the database, just as above
booksDao.getByAuthorId(bookId); // hits the database, just as above
```

The method from the DAO:

```
public List<Book> getByAuthorId(UUID... authorIds) {
        if (authorIds== null || authorIds.length == 0) {
            return Collections.emptyList();
        }

        Criteria criteria = getCurrentSession().createCriteria(Book.class)
                .add(in("authorId", authorIds));

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        List<Book> books= criteria.list();
        return books;
    }
```

Considering that the scenario where I am searching by the Author ID is quite often, I would like this also be cached, but can't manage to do this. Also, I would like to avoid activating hibernate.cache.use_query_cache

Comment: Why do you want to avoid activating the query cache? It exactly fits your purpose and it can be activated per query

Comment: I read that query cache add a lot of overhead and are not very effective. Also, the example is a very simplified version, so query caching may not even work for the actual queries that are executed.

Comment: The query cache definitively has shortcomings, but it might be useful especially if your application does not write often. Best thing would be to test it out (calling .setCacheable() on the criteria)

Answer (score 2):

This is not how Hibernate 2nd-level cache works.

The cache is basically a hash map. Keys are IDs, and values are the entities (to simplify).

If you want to access entities with a different key *e.g.* `authorId`, you need to set up a *different* hash map **and** handle the caching process yourself (if the entity is not found in the case, get it from the database and put it in the cache). The process can be helped with [JCache](https://github.com/jsr107/jsr107spec) for example, for which Hazelcast is also an implementation.

However, now, you've got 2 caches that are not synchronized with one another. Depending on your use-case, it might be fine, or it can lead to a lot of trouble.

Comment: I see. I thought that there was a possibility to have it configured with two caches (one by ID and one by authorId) that are kept in sync and I could not find it in the documentation.